# Can not run libpq examples in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, postgresql, visual-studio-2019, libpq

I am new to C++.
I downloaded https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/source/v13.1/postgresql-13.1.tar.gz from https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/source/ and unpacked it.

I created a new project in VS Community 2019. Added the example `postgresql-13.1\src\test\examples\testlibpq3.c` to the project.

Added my `postgresql-13.1\src\include` and `postgresql-13.1\src\interfaces\libpq` directories to `"Include Directories"` of the project.

Added `Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\lib` to `"Library Directories"` (this directory contains `libpq.lib`).

And when I try to compile, I get `postgresql-13.1\src\include\postgres_ext.h(26,10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'pg_config_ext.h': No such file or directory` error.

I looked for the `pg_config_ext.h` in `postgresql-13.1` directory. It's not there. Only `postgresql-13.1\src\include\pg_config_ext.h.in`.

Please tell me what am I missing? What's the easiest way to get the example to compile and run. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure, build and install PostgreSQL to have all the header files in the correct place.

It would be simpler to install the PostgreSQL binaries, they include all the header files necessary to build client code.